# Reattach Hyper-V Virtual Machine

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I copied my Hyper-V virtual machines from one disk to another by simply copying the 'Hyper-V' folder. Now I can't recreate the virtual machine. If I attempt to use Import, it fails; if I attach the virtual hard disk to a new virtual machine, it uses the oldest snapshot.

How do I recover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the fundamental problem, which is that "import failed," and you'll have to look at logs to see why that happened, you could recover by attaching the last .avhd file in the snapshot chain, rather than the original base .vhd file.

Of course, if you no longer have the original files, you're now out of luck. By mounting that original .vhd file, you've changed it and it no longer represents a useful parent image.  Child VHDs will have corrupt file systems because the blocks in the parent that they point to will be changed.

In general, if you can still boot the original machine, export the VMs, to the new location.  Then import them in place.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using server 2012 you can just pick the register option when importing the vm. This attaches and configures the vm to the hypervisor without needing to be exported first. However, if you have attached the vhd and mounted it or booted from it then your snapshots are now broken.

Comment: I don't remember seeing the register option (I was panicking a bit), and Jake was the first to respond with the advice to use the oldest AVHD, so he gets the rep.